Are UEFI runtime service functions always executed in SMM mode for x86?
For an OS to execute UEFI firmware provided functions, the most common ways is via SMM handlers which is entered by triggering SMI (System Manamagement Interrupt) that leads to running SMM hanlders provided by UEFI firmware. Another is SCI that would trigger OSPM to interprete ASL methods which are also provided by UEFI firmware.
I wonder are all UEFI runtime services provided by UEFI firmware always executed in SMM mode for x86 CPU?
There is a new mehod called PRM (Platform Runtime Mechanism) that is aimed to reduced the use of SMM but I haven't looked into it.
I searched for the web and did not find a conclusive answer.

No, in fact I would assume a firmware driver would strive not to invoke the SMM handler when writing UEFI runtime services.
The need for SMM arose before ACPI, when the firmware tried to stay as hidden as possible from the OS. With ACPI, we had a shift in paradigm: the firmware now explicitly tells the OS what to do and when with the AML bytecode in the ACPI tables.
In this new world, the need for SMM was reduced but not removed. SMM is still needed for the platform specific bookkeeping and handling, these are, however, internal details. Like handling the fans with a trip to SMM instead of using an in-hardware modulator.
But most importantly, the AML bytecode is, in fact, a generic bytecode, and doesn't allow for running native code. The handling of specific devices and their management through the ASL methods may require running some real code.
The trick used by the ASL writers was to use ASL to make the OS (unconsciously) raise an SMM (and some data somewhere to identify the request).
That's what PRM is aiming to change. This is, however, ACPI and not UEFI.
UEFI already has the runtime services in native code (you don't even need to change bitness as X-bit UEFI only load X-bit OSes).
The runtime services are accesses through ordinary function pointers (with the Windows ABI), they literally are function pointers into an executable area of physical memory marked as reserved by the firmware.
Since the OS is calling native code, there is no need to use the SMI trick to transition from AML to native code.  It's possible for the service handler to resort to SMM but that would only be due the way the firmware was modularized and designed.
Now if you read PRM you will see a lot of similarity with the runtime services, in fact that what's the specification was looking for. The PRM are the Runtime services for ACPI. And since they are so similar and PRM is more general (it defines a lot of data structures for modularity and pluggability) it could even replace the way runtime services are implemented.
With PRM all the custom ASL methods used to perform platform specific task (like translating a physical address into the socket/iMC/DIMM/bank/row/columns when an unrecoverable memory error happens) that needed native code and were handled in SMM, are now handled more efficientely.
But UEFI runtime services were already open to be implemented efficiently, so no, these routines are not always executed in SMM (actually, they almost never should).

Yeah I just found one that's not in SMM, should've tried to check the edk2 code. https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/master/PcAtChipsetPkg/PcatRealTimeClockRuntimeDxe/PcRtcEntry.c#L203

This is not a great question for stackoverflow, but this is a solid answer. However, there were definitely a bunch of (Atom?) platforms shipping with 32-bit UEFI while having 64-bit cpu - and running both Windows and Linux. Yes, it was messy.
